# Svelte not rendering values

Tags: svelte

I have a very simple Svelte app that's driving me nuts.

```
<script context="module">
        
    let data;
  const handleClick = async () => {
    data = self.crypto.randomUUID()
    console.log(data)
  };




</script>
  
<button on:click="{handleClick}">
    Click to Load Data
  </button>
  <pre>
    {data}
  </pre>
```

I can't seem to get the vault of `data` to render in my page. Just keep getting `undefined`. However `console.log` is writing out perfectly.

Comment: Why `async ` without any `await`? `data` seems eventually could only hold a value after a second click... Anyways... what do you get if you do `console.log(self)`?

Comment: I have tried it with an await. Not sure if it’s an asynchronous function though.

Comment: @user1513388 Adding `async` here make your callback function return a `promise`, usually we do that to be able to use `await` keyword to wait for a promise to be resolved inside our function, which you are not doing. You can safely remove `async` here.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `context="module"`. Working repl: https://svelte.dev/repl/501a655e8c2446d5bc2fc1acb1f13990?version=3.50.1